# Unable to get numeric result for font weight in chrome for selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
public class CssCheckCrome {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\shivamg\\Desktop\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

            driver.get("http://info.singtel.com/") ;
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1024, 768));

            System.out.println("Font weight of link "   + driver.findElement( By.linkText("Business") ) .getCssValue("font-weight")); // FONT WEIGHT
    }

}
```

Output -> Font weight of link normal

When I am running same code in Firefox and IE then I am getting Font-Weight=400, due to which my code failed during cross browser testing, Can someone tell me how can I get numeric result for chrome browser also. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this page](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/f/font-weight/) "normal" maps to 400 - I think you need to have your own mapping between font-weight keywords into numerical values:

```
normal -> 400
bold -> 700
```